# Is (n,m)=(18,7) the only positive solution to n^2 + n + 1 = m^3 ?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

It's hard to do a Google search on this problem.

If I was using Maple correctly, there are no other positive solutions with n at most 10000.

I know some of these Diophantine questions succumb to known methods, and others are extremely difficult to answer.

Comment: Yep. This problem succumbs to prime factorization in the Eisenstein integers Z[w]. 

Comment: @Qiaochu, Do you mean 'Yep, it's the only answer' or 'Yep, it succumbs to known methods' or 'Yep, it's extremely difficult to answer'? :)

Comment: Write as $(8n+1)^2=(4m)^3-48$, which is Mordell's equation for $k=-48$. A quick google comes up with the following, http://www.lrz.de/~hr/numb/mordell.html#tbl3. There's only two solutions for $4m\le10^{10}$. One solution is $m=1$ (hence, $n=0$). The other must be the one you state. 

Comment: @David: the first two. (I always default to responding to the title question.) 

Comment: A google search gives the following by Keith Conrad describing the methods. http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf. In this case, you'd factorize in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Did you just post and delete an answer? It seemed quite good to me. I was about to point out a missing factor of $\omega$ or $\omega^2$, but it vanished.

Comment: @George, that's $(8n+4)^2=(4m)^3-48$. The problem is discussed on pages 208-209 of Mordell, Diophantine Equations. The solution is ascribed to W Ljunggren, Einige Bemerkungen uber die Darstellung ganzer Zahlen durch binare kubische Formen mit positiver Diskriminante, Acta Math 75 (1942) 1-21. 

Comment: @Gerry: yes, sorry, should have been "+ 4"

Comment: @George: I seem to have missed a subtlety as zeb pointed out. 

Comment: @Gerry: Thank you for pointing out that y^2 = x^3 - 48 is explicitly dealt with in Mordell's book.  Thank you everyone else for your feedback too.

Possible digression: My reason for considering the above question was the following "quickie":  Prove that if n>0, then n+2 and n^2+n+1 cannot simultaneously be perfect cubes.  (You don't need any algebraic number theory to answer the "quickie".)

Comment: I don't really understand this fact: For solving an equation of the form $aX^{2}+bX+C = M^{3}$ why do we need to translate this problem into algebraic number theoritical methods. Can't we have a purely elementary solution. :(

Comment: This question was apparently one of two challenges issued by Fermat in 1657, the other being the “inverse” equation $1+x+x^2+x^3=y^2$. Mahoney points out that Fermat didn't comment on the solution of this one (though he did solve the companion), but suggests both can be reduced to a Pell equation $u^2-dv^2=\pm k$. While I can see how the companion would be so transformed, can anyone tell me how this one would be turned into a Pell equation?

Comment: @S.C. The answer to your question "Can't we have a purely elementary solution[?]" is "Yes, we can!"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

sage: E = EllipticCurve([0,0,1,0,-1])

sage: E

Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + y = x^3 - 1 over Rational Field

sage: E.integral_points()

[(1 : 0 : 1), (7 : 18 : 1)]

Comment: In other words: There is a lot of research available on integral points on elliptic curves and the resulting algorithm is implemented in sage and magma. See for instance chapter XIII of Smart's "Tha Algorithmic Resolution of Diophantine Equations". The sage documentation of this function refers to Petho A., Zimmer H.G., Gebel J. and Herrmann E., Computing all S-integral points on elliptic curves Math. Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc. (1999), 127, 383-402.

Answer (score 7):

Let $\omega$ be a third root of unity, then $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is a PID.

We have $m^3 = n^2 + n + 1 = (n-\omega)(n-\omega^2)$.

$\gcd(n-\omega,n-\omega^2) = \gcd(n-\omega,\omega-\omega^2) \mid (1-\omega)$, and $(1-\omega)$ is the ramified prime lying over $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, so from unique factorization of $m^3$ we get that either $(n-\omega)$ and $(n-\omega^2)$ are both roots of unity times cubes, or one is a root of unity times $(1-\omega)$ times a cube and the other is a root of unity times $3$ times a cube. In the second case, $m$ is a multiple of $3$, but then $n^2 + n + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 9$, which is impossible.

If $(n-\omega)$ and $(n-\omega^2)$ are cubes, say $a^3$ and $\bar{a}^3$, then their difference $\omega^2-\omega$ is $a^3-\bar{a}^3 = (a-\bar{a})(a^2+a\bar{a}+\bar{a}^2)$. Thus $a-\bar{a}$ is either a root of unity or a root of unity times $(1-\omega)$, and it must be the latter since $a-\bar{a}$ is pure imaginary. Thus $\Im a \le \Im (\omega-\omega^2) = \sqrt{3}$. The same argument applied to $\omega a$ shows that $\Im \omega a \le \sqrt{3}$, and similarly for other roots of unity times $a$, so $a$ is in a hexagon around the origin that is contained in a circle of radius $2$ around the origin, i.e. $|a| \le 2$, so $m = |a|^2 \le 4$. which doesn't give us any solutions.

Finally we have the case that one of $(n-\omega), (n-\omega^2)$ is of the form $\omega a^3$. Then we have $\pm(\omega^2-\omega) = \omega a^3 - \omega^2 \bar{a}^3$. Write $a = x+y\omega$. Then $\omega a^3 - \omega^2 \bar{a}^3 = (\omega-\omega^2)(x^3+y^3-3x^2y)$, so we have $x^3+y^3-3x^2y = \pm 1$, which is a Thue equation. One solution is $x = -1, y = 2$, leading to the solution $n = 18, m = 7$.

Edit: Mathematica claims that the only solutions to $x^3+y^3-3x^2y = 1$ are $(x,y) = (-2, -3), (-1, -1), (-1, 2), (0, 1), (1, 0), (3, 1)$. Mathematica's documentation says it computes an explicit bound on the size of a solution to a Thue equation based on the Baker-Wustholz theorem in order to solve it, and in this case it seems like the bound was small enough.

Comment: zeb: Nice, but a disappointing finish. We started off by looking for integer points on an elliptic curve, so it seems to have gone in a bit of a circle.

Comment: Mordell, following Ljunggren, solves $x^3-3xy^2-y^3=1$ on pages 208-209 of Diophantine Equations, as noted in my other comment. He has to go to the degree 6 field ${\bf Q}(\sqrt\xi)$, where $\xi$ is a root of $z^3-3z+1=0$, find the 4 fundamental units, and apply 2-adic methods. 

Comment: George - I realized this almost immediately after posting my answer. Well, at least the new equation seems simpler to me (are Thue equations easier to deal with than general elliptic curves?)

Comment: @zeb: Write $p(z)=z^3-3z+1$, so the equation becomes $p(y/x)=\pm x^{-3}$, so the theory of Diophantine approximation tells you that there are only finitely many solutions. That is $y/x$ approximates the roots of $p$. Although, as Gerry mentions, this is already solved by Mordell.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, and has already been well-answered, but what I've got to say is slightly too long for a comment...

The equation $x^2+x+1 = y^3$ is of interest to finite geometers because $x^2+x+1$ is the number of points (and lines) in a finite projective plane of order $x$.

People have mentioned Ljunggren's name in comments above. The paper that's relevant is this:

> Ljunggren, Wilhelm
>   Einige Bemerkungen über die Darstellung ganzer Zahlen durch binäre kubische Formen mit positiver Diskriminante. (German)
>   Acta Math. 75, (1943). 1–21.

I heartily recommend the Mathscinet review of that article, which says (amongst other things)...

... that Nagell [Norsk Mat. Forenings Skr. (I) no. 2 (1921)] proved that the equation

> (1) $x^2+x+1=y^n$

has only trivial solutions unless $n$ is a power of $3$...

...  And that Ljunggren then proved that (1) has only two nontrivial solutions, namely (18,7) and (-19, 7), for n=3.

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is a massive revival/refresh of this question, but I just found a completely elementary solution of this problem, outlined in [this MSE question and my own answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904457/looking-for-help-with-this-elementary-method-of-finding-integer-solutions-on-an).

Does anyone know if there are other completely elementary solutions?

Comment: It is unclear to me why y-1 divides x.  Are you assuming y-1  is a power of two times a prime?  Gerhard "Would Like Very Elementary Proof" Paseman, 2016.03.09.

Comment: (3.3)-(3.2) yields $y-1=a-d$. Since (4) implies
$$
 x(3y-2) = x\left(3(y-1)+1\right) \equiv 0 \pmod{a-d},
$$
we conclude $(y-1) \mid x$. Right? Note that even without working out $c=1$, this conclusion holds.

Comment: (I'll be submitting this result for publication; the proof outlined on MSE will be made rigorous with those sorts of details.)

Comment: I am still not seeing c=1.  I do see (a-d) dividing both x and y-1 however.  If you can show me c=1, then I will work through the rest of it.  If you (figure out my address and) send me an email, there is the chance I can review your MS before you submit it.  We can discuss that issue over email.  Gerhard "Seeing C's Is Not Unseemly" Paseman, 2016.03.09.

Comment: I will reconstruct (or, perhaps, find in my 2014 Tagebuch/sketches?) the "few simple congruence and divisibility arguments" that I indicate I used [almost two years ago now!] to obtain $c=1$. To be honest, I just don't currently recall what they were/are.

Comment: I just reviewed the rest.  If you can prove c =1 ( or work the argument to success with (y-1)q=cx with small enough c ), I will offer to review your manuscript before submission.  Gerhard "For The Advancement Of Science" Paseman, 2016.03.09.

Comment: Recovered $c=1$. (It wasn't in my Tagebuch after all… what _was_ there is a lovely attempt at generalizing the method, which I'll now be reviewing more closely.) It's actually quite direct, once you see it!

Comment: I am looking forward to seeing it.  Gerhard "Ok.  I Give.  Hint, Please." Paseman, 2016.03.10.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Both $y^3+x$ and $y^3-3x$ are squares, and $c = \gcd(y-1,x+1)$. If you need more hints, I'm afraid you'll have to wait and read the paper.  ;)

Comment: Thanks. I'll see what I can do with that. (Incidentally, if I use x=-19, I get c=6 or -6.  You must be using positivity in some crucial and to me nonobvious way.)  Gerhard "Looking Forward To Manuscript Checking" Paseman, 2016.03.11.

Comment: If $a,b$ are of unknown sign, then $(a+b) \mid c$ carries less [well, effectively no] information regarding magnitude. But if $a,b > 0$, then one can usually leverage $(a+b) \mid c$ into information about the magnitude of various expressions.

Comment: You mention in the other post that x is even (assuming x > 0).  How is that proved?  Gerhard "Needs To Work Into This" Paseman, 2016.03.12.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Hmmm… __that__ maybe a gap I can't fill! I seem to have assumed $x$ is even; I don't see anywhere (implied or written down) where I did otherwise. I'll get back to you — thanks for the catch.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: D'oh! It doesn't matter! I mentioned $x$ is even _after_ the point at which the new proof forks off. In other words, the new proof handles all cases. Whew!

Comment: Is there any update on the paper?

Comment: Looking at the Nagell paper more closely, I realized my method provides no real benefit over his when it comes to the main equation — indeed, his is superior (more general). So I set the paper aside until I can generalize my method to be applicable beyond this [class of] equation.